# Modelling Oxygen Diffusion

Tags: ideal-gas, diffusion

I am creating a system of differential equations to model oxygen diffusion in tissue.

I have:

$\frac{dP}{dt}=D_o\nabla^2P-qn$

where $q$ represents the sink rate at positions occupied by cells, $n$ the number of cells at the position and P ($PPO_2$) is represented in mmHg. $D_o$ is the diffusivity of oxygen in tissue, for now assumed to be 1 (subject to change).

My problem is, q is expressed in $mol \times cell^{-1} \times s^{-1}$, ie:

$q=2.5 \times 10^{-8} mol_{O^2} \times cell^{-1} \times s^{-1}$

The volume of each position in my grid is of $2.1 \times 10^{-7} cm^3$. So ideally my sink rate should be the number of cells at the position multiplied by the oxygen consumption rate q. However, the units are different and I am lost as to how to reconcile this.

I am assuming there is only oxygen at each position. Any thoughts?

EDIT: As mentioned in comments, I am assuming a diffusivity of 1 and a temperature of 38 celcius.

Comment: I've never heard of diffusion of pressure. Are you sure this is what you want? Also, your laplacian term also doesn't work... All three terms have different units in your equation

Comment: @AaronStevens For an ideal gas of uniform temperature, density is proportional to pressure, so I don't see why diffusion of pressure by itself is wrong. That said, the Laplacian term just needs a diffusivity constant applied to fix the units. To convert between mol of oxygen and pressure, we also need to know the temperature of the oxygen, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @probably_someone my apologies, for now I am just assuming a diffusivity of 1 , although I plan on changing that later. I am modelling this within the human body, so I suppose for now I'd set a temperature of ~38 celcius. Let me amend the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your typical diffusion equation with a sink is given by
$$\frac{\partial n}{\partial t}=D\nabla^2 n-qn$$

Where $n$ is a number of particles, $D$ is a diffusion constant, and $q$ is a rate of particle removal from the system.

Im not familiar with pressure diffusion (I'm sure you can express diffusion in this way though). Where did you get your equation from?

Comment: Trying to work out a simplification of tissue division given in : https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s002850200135 where diffusion is applied to pressure.

Comment: Ok so here's a thought (and I might be entirely wrong). If I have P = (nrt)/v I know V, R,T and N I could use this to express the uptake rate in terms of pressure?

Comment: @DarioP which equation specifically?

Comment: That might be fine

Comment: Stevenes eq6 in the paper

Comment: @DarioP I'll look over it when I have time. At first glance equation 6 looks different than what you are doing. Are they just looking at steady state there?